# Duvida sobre estrutura básica do Laravel!

Tags: php, laravel, aplicação-web

Existe alguma recomendação a seguir do framework Laravel ao iniciar um projeto?
pergunto isso porque ao iniciar um projeto já vem por padrão com algumas estruturas predefinidas!

vi que vem com algumas migrations predefinidas
[image: Migrations]

Vi que tbm vem com um Model predefinido
[image: Model]

Vi que tbm vem uma Factory já criada pra inserção de dados
[image: Factory]

A minha duvida é a seguinte, o laravel por padrão na versão mais nova (v8.52.0), no momento que estou postando essa duvida.
Por padrão tras uma estrutura de exemplo, pra criação de um sistema de autenticação!
1 - Existe um tutorial/documentação pra eu entender melhor como continuar essa limpa implementação que vem junto com o laravel??
Ou eu sou livre pra continuar essa limpa implementação da forma q eu bem entender?
olhando pra essa limpa implementação vi uma boa organização, e uma boa convenção pra um sistema de autenticação!
Gostaria de seguir essa limpa implementação sugerida pelo laravel!
mais gostaria de entende-la melhor...
2 - a migration failed_jobs, que já vem predefinida na lista de migrations do laravel, Faz parte da recomendação do sistema de autenticação?
ou essa migration já vem predefinida pra que o laravel por padrão, possa registrar filas de eventos que tenham falhado?
3 - essa estrutura de autenticação que vem junto com o laravel, tem algo haver com o laravel/ui, ou com o laravel/jetstream ?
reparei q o laravel/ui, aproveita essa estrutura base que vem juntamente com o projeto laravel.
4 - o package laravel/ui, e o laravel/jetstream, é recomendado usar-los?
eu fiz um curso de laravel na udemy, onde o instrutor do curso ensinou usar o laravel/ui, curti bastante!
Só teve alguns pontos onde eu não gostei muito, reparei q ele exige que eu escolha entre bootstrap, vue ou react!
Sei que eu posso editar o front pra minha necessidade... mais acho q seria trabalhoso pra quem é iniciante no laravel!
estou querendo iniciar um projeto de gerenciamento de estoque, porem antes de iniciar, quero me informar melhor sobre essa questão de autenticação no laravel, Pois fiquei com algumas duvidas referente a isso..
Já que o laravel tras uma estrutura base implementada com um projeto limpo!
Desculpa a duvida gigante galera, é que não deu pra resumir!

Comment: 1  leia a doc, é muito boa. 2 failed_jobs filas que falharam. 3 Independente de qual for utilizar recomendo fuçar bem pra entender (ex Alterar login com email pra username etc) 4. Nunca tive problemas e acho uma mão na roda. Na prática ele é trataais de questões de layout. Dá uma olhada no Github do Laravel ui pra ter uma visão melhor de como funcionam as coisas

Answer (score 0):

Os padrões do Laravel devem ser seguidos e para facilitar o laravel tem o `artisan` que tem vários comandos, por exemplo, para criação de model, de factory, de controller, de migration... Utilizando os comandos as estruturas criadas são mantidas.

`failed_jobs` é exatamente o que você falou, uma tabela para os `jobs` que falharam, não faz parte da autenticação desde que você não use verificação de email ou redefinição de senha com envio de emails usando fila.

A autenticação do laravel ajuda muito, ta tudo pronto, dificilmente você terá um fluxo de autenticação diferente do que já vem no laravel e às vezes que precisei mudar algo só precisei sobrescrever um ou outro método no `LoginController`.

Não tenho nada a reclamar do pacote `laravel/ui`, caso você não manje de frontend ele vai configurar tudo que você precisa para começar a utilizar vue ou outro framework que ele suporte. Caso você manje de frontend e saiba as dependências que não são necessárias para seu projeto, basta remove-las após a instalação do `laravel/ui`.

Enfim, tudo que você perguntou tem na documentação, não tenha medo de ler, é uma ótima documentação. Caso prefira um curso, tem vários no youtube como esse https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=376vZ1wNYPA.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito bom. Só discordo de "não faz parte da autenticação desde..." Ainda que usar no cenário citado,  failed_jobs não irá tratar questões de autenticação em geral, apenas trata de um processamento (envio do email) que falhou

Comment: Verdade.
Eu só quis deixar claro que é uma "feature" do Laravel que também é utilizada pela autenticação caso você utilize fila para envio de e-mails, mas realmente não faz parte da autenticação.